# Как сгенерировать массив с повторяющимися строками Python

Tags: python, numpy

Имеется одномерный массив чисел (длина 2*10**6). Прошу прощение за наглость, но существует ли более быстрый способ сгенерировать два массива, чтобы в одном
массиве каждая горизонтальная строка массива повторяла элементы исходного одномерного массива. Во втором массиве вертикальные столбцы должны повторять исходный одномерный массив.
Получается два транспонированных массива. Индексирование или транспонирование у меня получается медленнее.
В примере использован более короткий массив.

```
import numpy as np
import time
N = 2*10**6
m_0 = np.arange(N)

t1 = time.time()
m_1 = np.tile(m_0, N)
m_2 = np.repeat(m_0, N)
print(time.time() - t1)
print(m_1)
print(m_2)
```

Comment: А где вы делаете транспонирование? Можете привести в вопросе маленький пример входных данных (3-5 строк) и результат, который вы хотите получить? Пока не очень понятно, т.к. описание не соответствует коду.

Comment: Приведенный вами пример не соответствует описанию в тексте вопроса. У вас в примере порождаются две строки, а в вопросе - стоят слова "каждая строка" и "столбцы", что якобы намекает на то, что у вас должна получиться матрица. Согласуйте одно с другим.

Comment: Конкретизировал

Comment: Без воспроизводимого примера данных и результата - ничего не понятно. Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Повторю вопрос. У вас в программе генерируется не многомерные массивы, а одномерные вектора. Если не верите, выполните  m_1.shape и m_2.shape. В обоих случаях получите (40000000,).  А в вопросе фигурирует слова "каждая горизонтальная строка", что подразумевает множественность строк, и слово "вертикальные столбцы" что опять таки подразумевает их множественность. Ни многих строк ни много столбцов вы в примере не генерируете. Где ошибка?

Comment: Вы хотите построить массив `(2*10^6)*(2*10^6)*8` (высота x ширина x байт на элемент). Это `32*10^12`. 32 террабайта данных. У вас нет такой памяти. Тут нечего ускорять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, пока ТС так и не разобрался, что и как он генерирует, приведу пример того, как можно дублировать одну строку массива "вниз", превратив массив в матрицу, или один столбец "вправо", превратив его тоже в матрицу. Не уверен, что это то, чего хочет ТС, но за неимением вразумительного пояснения или примера -  может кому пригодится.
(Разумеется,  размерность будет "игрушечная", что-бы видеть, что происходит).
Итак имеем начальный одномерный массив:

```
m_0 = np.arange(5)
```

Выглядит от так:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Создаем его копию:

```
m_01=m_0[:]
```

и "растягиваем" исходный массив "вниз":

```
for i in range(4):
    m_01=np.vstack((m_01, m_0)) 
print (m_01)
```

Результат:

```
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3 4]]
```

Теперь займемся растяжкой вправо:

Превращаем исходную строку в одномерный вектор:

```
m_2=m_0[:,np.newaxis]
```

и растягиваем его "вправо"

```
m_21=m_2[:]
for i in range(4):
    m_21=np.hstack((m_21, m_2)) 
print (m_21)
```

Результат:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4]]
```

Имеем две транспонированые матрицы, как ТС и просил.